# Wait until function is finished using $.when

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert my page to PDF.

I have two pages that are converted into base64 encoded image then added into a PDF using jsPDF. It works fine.

My problem is I want the code below wait for the domtoimage function to be treated before saving it.

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();

//First
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('page'))
.then(function (dataUrl) {
           doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'png', 15, 10, 180, 280);
           doc.addPage();
});
//Second
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('page2'))
.then(function (dataUrl) {
            doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'png', 15, 10, 180, 280);    });
//Third
doc.save("file.pdf");
```

I found this solution: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ but as I am not familiar with promise I don't know how to make it work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe `.delay(ms)` can help. Otherwise you can use the `setTimeout()` function. Read more about delay here: https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: `.delay` only applies to the effects queue (eg fadeIn/slideDown).  It's not for general "wait a specific time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

//First
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('page'))
.then(function (dataUrl) {
    doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'png', 15, 10, 180, 280);
    doc.addPage();
    domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('page2')).then(function (dataUrl) {
        doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'png', 15, 10, 180, 280);
        doc.save("file.pdf");
    });
});
```

Comment: Not the kind of answer I expected but it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

//First
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('page'))
.then(function (dataUrl) {
           doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'png', 15, 10, 180, 280);
           doc.addPage();

           //Second
           domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('page2'))
              .then(function (dataUrl) {
                  doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'png', 15, 10, 180, 280);

                  //Third
                  doc.save("file.pdf");    
              });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.when() for this..

```
function func1(){
  domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('page'))
   .then(function (dataUrl) {
       doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'png', 15, 10, 180, 280);
       doc.addPage();
  });
}

function func2(){
  domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('page2'))
  .then(function (dataUrl) {
        doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'png', 15, 10, 180, 280);    });
}

$.when(func1(), func2())
 .done(function(){
    doc.save("file.pdf");
  }).fail(function(){
       console.log('failure');
 });
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It gives me a blank PDF meaning it saves before executing the two function :/

Comment: did u initialize doc??

Comment: Yes, I did. I think the domtoimage function are treated in the background because it takes a few seconds to generate the image. So it saves first and goes back to domtoimage to finish treatement

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below:

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();

$.when(fn1()).done(function (v1) {
  console.log(v1);
});

//First
function fn1() {
  domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('page'))
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
      doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'png', 15, 10, 180, 280);
      doc.addPage();

      // Call next function.
      $.when(fn2()).done(function(v2) {
        console.log(v2);
      });
  });

  return 'success';
}

//Second
function fn2() {
  domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('page2'))
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
      doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'png', 15, 10, 180, 280);

      // Call next function.
      $.when(fn3()).done(function(v3) {
        console.log(v3);
      });
    });

  return 'success';
}

//Third
function fn3() {
  doc.save("file.pdf");

  return 'success';
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The function are called in the good order fn1 then fn2 then fn3 but I think that the function domtoimage are still processed in the background. Result it saves first the PDF then execute the domtoimage

Comment: @Knriano, I've updated code and added promise in other function as well. Will it be possible for you to give it a try and update us if this works?

Comment: Thanks @Knriano for confirming.